# Voice Effects Ios SDK

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, voice

Tell me, are there any libraries that Ios SDK, with which you can add effects to the voice. That is necessary to make the voice of a speaker. that is something that is said in mokrofon, add effects horn and transmitted to the headphones (speaker)

Comment: Please read [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You can not ask question straight away for which you have not made any efforts.

Comment: The efforts I made, just have not found I need help in finding bibioteki. or how it is possible in principle to do so. where to look and what to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into DSP, (Digital signal processing). This won't come easy as it does get rather complicated (ever heard of a Fourier transform?). Start by trying to make something react to audio first as you will learn a lot about how to do what you want to do.

tl;dr: there is no magic way to do this without putting some time into learning it.